# mandrill template '@' stripped out from email address

Tags: mandrill, querystringparameter

I'm using the Mandrill API to send html email. I have a link in my template that contains a query string with an email address, however the '@' sign is stripped out when receiving the email.

I'm using global_merge_vars thus:

```
'global_merge_vars' => array(
                        array(
                            'name' => 'merge1',
                            'content' => 'merge1 content'
                        ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'UEMAIL',
                    'content' => $uEmail
                )
                    ),
```

Example of the link:
http://www.test.com/?email=test@test.com

is received as

http://www.test.com/?email=testtest.com

How can I prevent the '@' from being stripped out?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to escape the @ sign! I think it is %40

Comment: @Azd325 aha! I (wrongly) assumed that Madrill would take care of that for me. Ran the email address through a url encode function and that's fixed it. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to encode your url because the `@` sign is special character.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to URL encode the email address parameter before passing it to Mandrill.

It looks like you're writing in PHP? Try the [urlencode function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).